# Process specific element in array python

Tags: python

I had array from processed data that i get in Internet which i copied and the result is
`data=[[655.0, 48.77, 6.0, '1'], 0.0, [655.0, 48.77, 5.0, '1'], 1.0, [657.0, 49.25, 5.0, '4'], 2.2870067774276484, [657.0, 49.25, 1.0, '1'], 5.40651458890106, [657.0, 49.25, 1.0, '5'], 5.40651458890106]`

I just confuse how I read that array. I want to copy an array of data to become a new one like

`new = [['1',0.0],['1',1.0],['4',2.287006],['1',5.4065145],['5',5.4065145]]`

Best regard.

Comment: so you want a final string from each nested array, and the element (not inside the nested array) right after..?

Comment: Start by explaining in words which parts of `data` you want to extract and put in `new`. For your own purposes, feel free to use whatever spoken or written language you know best.

Comment: I want to extract as i said , there a number what i called it label which include (1,4,5) and i wanna mix that label with 0.0 , 1.0, 2.28700, 5.406 and 5.406 which i called it distance into new array. Thanks sorry for bad english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume that you deal with a constant order of the data structure like the list you provided in your example.

If i understand well :

You got an input list of nested lists and some floats.

```
[ [ A, B, C, D ], somefloat, [A, B, C, D ] somefloat ]
```

And you try to get a list of nested lists which take the last element of the first nested list and combine it with the next float into a new nested list like so :

```
[ [D, somefloat], [D, somefloat] ]
```

One solution could be to use list comprehension, like so :

```
data=[[655.0, 48.77, 6.0, '1'], 0.0, [655.0, 48.77, 5.0, '1'], 1.0, [657.0, 49.25, 5.0, '4'], 2.2870067774276484, [657.0, 49.25, 1.0, '1'], 5.40651458890106, [657.0, 49.25, 1.0, '5'], 5.40651458890106]

newdata = [[data[i][-1], data[i +1]] for i in range(0, len(data), 2)]
print(newdata)
```

**Output**

```
[['1', 0.0], ['1', 1.0], ['4', 2.2870067774276484], ['1', 5.40651458890106], ['5', 5.40651458890106]]
```

Let's break it down :

```
for i in range(0, len(data), 2) 
# will iterate through the first list, the range method here (starts from 0 to the length of the input list) will return the current index as "i" with step of two, for each iteration.

[data[i][-1]
#will take the current item (which is a nested list) and extract from it the last element, feel free to change the -1 by any index of the element you desire (if you decide to finally go with the third element, so change the -1 -which mean the last element- by 2 -which is the third element


data[i +1]
# will take the next element (which is the float number)

[data[i][-1], data[i +1]
# will put them in a nested list (feel free to use tuple or dict if you want to output another kind of nested data structure)
```